# Battling the ad-hoc limited URL syntax

Tags: bug, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links to Wolfram alpha don't appear](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/520/links-to-wolfram-alpha-dont-appear)

I'm wasting too much time having to figure out how to correctly quote URL's to get them to match the limited subset allowed here (by markdown?), e.g. see the 3rd link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11686/is-there-a-rational-number-with-denominator-not-greater-than-200-between-15-106/11690#11690) and, more frequently, quote characters in Wiki links, etc. One should be able to simply cut and paste links without having to figure out which characters need to be quoted. Is there some easy way to workaround this limitation?

Comment: @KennyTM: It might be a good idea to retitle the WolframAlpha question to be a generic why-are-my-URLs-broken question. Otherwise, if someone is having similar problems with the URL syntax, they wouldn't be able to find the existing question on meta, and will keep asking duplicate questions.

Comment: @Rahul: Done. [ ](http://.)